# Access Mainframe (Z/OS) Flat files

Tags: powerbi, sftp, mainframe

I have been tasked to research Power BI Connection to Mainframe Flat files in some cases vsam files
This is needed to replace an existing Legacy BI tool/Reporting  that connects to Mainframe

POWER BI does not have a direct connection to Mainframe , so what would be the best way to connect to data sources (Flat files in some cases vsam files, if we need to convert vsam files to flat, we will do it)

Is there any third party tools that can can be used to bridge this gap between Power BI (or any other BI Tool) and the Mainframe data files (our shop already converts Vsam files to Flat files)
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though, this is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it my way, but it really only works for smaller, text-based files.

I have some code on the mainframe that converts the data in question into a sensible .csv format. I then compose and send an email on the mainframe to myself from a pre-defined email address (in my case I use "SAVE_TO_SHAREPOINT@<company_name>.com" with the .CSV data as an attachment.

I use Power Automate to pick up emails to myself from that email address and save the attachment to a SharePoint folder that is specified as the subject of the email.

This process can be automated to run whenever it is required. You can then use Power BI to pull in the .csv data fromthe specified SharePoint folder.

This won't work for everyone, but it currently works for me.

You could  also use FTP, but you can't FTP to SharePoint, so you'd have to work out how you want the FTP'd data to get into Power BI.

Comment: Thanks Steve .. Is there like an ODBC connection to mainframe datasets ?

Comment: @CountryBoy I don’t know. There may be some solution out there. My solution works where a live connection isn’t required.